# Picture in picture mode

Tags: software-recommendation

I shifted from elementary os to ubuntu last week I miss picture in picture mode which elementary os offered I could put anything in picture in picture mode is there a way to get it in ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know Elementary OS - do you mean picture-in-picture within browser or out of the browser? Within browser, current versions of Firefox support it out of the box, there's no need to do anything.

Comment: Picture in picture mode in elementary os puts any part of screen in pip mode

Answer (score 0):

**Enable Picture in Picture on Ubuntu**
To get set up and enable a floating window on Ubuntu you will need to be running the GNOME Shell desktop:

apt:gnome-shell

You then need to install the Window Preview extension from the GNOME Extensions website:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1227/window-corner-preview/

When installed and enabled you will see a small ‘monkey’ icon in the status area. Click on this monkey icon and set the in-menu toggle switch for window preview from ‘off’ to ‘on’.

Finally, select a window or workspace to preview.

To preview a YouTube video simply drag the tab out of your browser, move it to another workspace, and enter full-screen. Then switch to another workspace to continue working with the video on show.

Comment: Extension doesn't get installed

Comment: doesn't work with gnome 3.36

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give the Miniview extension a try:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1459/miniview/

I haven't used Elementary OS, but its picture-in-picture looks slick!